# Postgres Trigger to INSERT UPDATE DELETE on similar derivative table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

Description:

- I am running `postgresql 13`
- I have two tables under different schemas, `t1` and `t2`.
- `t2` is derivative of `t1` in the sense that they share all the same
  columns and data, but `t2` is always downstream of `t1` as far as
  validity.
- The rows in both tables share the same primary key, which is what I assume would be used as the link between them.

The ask:

- I would like to create a trigger that reflects any changes in `t1` and syncs `t2` to be the same.
- I started with `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, but if `DELETE` is easily added, I would like to implement that as well.

Trigger Code:

```sql
-- Trigger for t1 to t2 --

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t1_schema.sync_trigger()

RETURNS TRIGGER AS

$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t2_schema.t2 (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
    
CREATE TRIGGER t1t2_test_sync
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON t1_schema.t1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_schema.sync_trigger()
```

When I execute this code and do a test `UPDATE` on `t1`, the same row on `t2` does not reflect the changes or give me any errors.

I have tried:

- Discretely labeling all rows as updated with `NEW.` format, but run into the problem of primary key column not being editable in `t2`.
- Adding a `WHERE` clause after the `VALUES` clause, something like `WHERE primary_key=NEW.primary_key`, but I get an error.
- Another option I have seen is adding an `IF` statement before the
  `INSERT`, or adding a `WHEN` clause in the trigger, but neither have
  worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(A) Solution based on triggers**

You maybe get an error when updating a row in `t1` because your trigger function tries to insert a new row in `t2` which has alreday been inserted in `t2` by the same trigger function when it has been inserted in `t1`. You need to duplicate and specialize your trigger functions, one for insert, one for update, one for delete because the treatment to be triggered on `t2` is different :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t1_schema.sync_trigger_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t2_schema.t2 (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3);
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER t1t2_test_sync_insert
AFTER INSERT ON t1_schema.t1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_schema.sync_trigger_insert() ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t1_schema.sync_trigger_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE t2
       SET col1 = NEW.col1
         , col2 = NEW.col2
         , col3 = NEW.col3
     WHERE primary_key_t2 = NEW. primary_key_t1 ; -- primary_key_t2 must be replaced by the set of columns which are in the primary key of t2 with AND operators, the same for NEW.primary_key_t1
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER t1t2_test_sync_update
AFTER UPDATE ON t1_schema.t1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_schema.sync_trigger_update() ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t1_schema.sync_trigger_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM t2
     WHERE primary_key_t2 = NEW. primary_key_t1 ; -- primary_key_t2 must be replaced by the set of columns which are in the primary key of t2 with AND operators, the same for NEW.primary_key_t1
    RETURN OLD; -- NEW is not available for triggers ON DELETE
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER t1t2_test_sync_delete
AFTER DELETE ON t1_schema.t1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_schema.sync_trigger_delete() ;
```

**(B) Solution based on foreign key**

It is possible that a foreign key on `t2 (col1,col2,col3)` referencing `t1 (col1, col2, col3)` with the options `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` may deliver your expected result in a much more simple and efficient way, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). In this case, you don't need the triggers `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` anymore, but you still need the trigger `ON INSERT`.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you. I will look into (B) once I have a working A.

I had a little bit of trouble understanding the `WHERE` clause of `UPDATE` and `DELETE` functions. 

Let's say the primary key column in both tables is called `pk`, and I am changing `col1` `col2` `col3` in both tables.

What would the syntax be for the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Let's say the primary key is defined on (col2, col3, col7) then the WHERE clause is `WHERE col2 = NEW.col2 AND col3 = NEW.col3 AND col7 = NEW.col7`

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach is to **not create** t2 as a table. Instead create it as a **VIEW** on t1. This totally eliminates triggers to keep them synchronized because the actual source is the same. Follows the concept to store a single data point in only 1 place.  Keep in mind that *if you store a single piece in 2 places, 1 on them will be wrong* at some point. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a30ece08dc35a360f7dcd7268de5948)).

```
create view soq2.t2 as 
            select * 
              from soq1.t1;
```

Also if you need column names to change then use an alias during the create view;

```
create view soq2.t2a as 
       select t1_id  as t2_id
            , name   as t2_name 
            , status as t2_status
         from soq1.t1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. For our use case, the insistence is on doing this with trigger functions. I did bring up views in the initial discussion but I do not remember why the path forward ended up being triggers.  I will inquire further and follow up, maybe you are right. =)

Comment: Then the solution proposed by @Edouard is about as good as it gets. You will probably both A and B from it. Also an often overlooked issue with trigger based implementation is `TRUNCATE`.  What do you do then?

Comment: Also a good question! I will discuss it with my counterpart. Thank you very much.